# How to copy a SharePoint page with CSOM?

Tags: development, csom

I'm trying to copy a SharePoint page in page library and copy it to another site, i tried use copyTo method but only works for files in the same site and i want to copy to anothe site in the same sitecollection

Here is my code:

```
using (ClientContext clientcontext = new ClientContext("https://server/siteSource")) {
  using (ClientContext clientcontext2 = new ClientContext("https://server/siteDestination")) { 
  //Activate sharepoint server publishing to create page library y siteDestination
    Guid guid = new Guid("94c94ca6-b32f-4da9-a9e3-1f3d343d7ecb");
    var web = clientcontext2.Web;
    var webSrc = clientcontext.Web;
    web.Features.Add(guid, true, FeatureDefinitionScope.None);
    clientcontext2.ExecuteQuery();
    clientcontext.Load(clientcontext.Web.Lists);
    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
   //search page library in siteSource
   foreach (List list in clientcontext.Web.Lists) {
      if (list.Title.ToString() == "Pages") {
          //retrieve a page
          clientcontext.Load(list.RootFolder.Files);
          File pagina = list.RootFolder.Files.Where(x => x.Name == "Inicio.aspx").First();

          //copyTo method for copy page to siteDestination

      }
   }
  }
}
```

UPDATE

i added this code for retrieve the page form the library

```
                clientcontext.Load(clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages"));
                var paginas = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
                clientcontext.Load(paginas.RootFolder.Files);
                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (File pag in paginas.RootFolder.Files)
            {
               if (pag.Name.ToString() == "Inicio.aspx")
                {
                        //Copy page to another site
                }
            }
```

i found this code for use the Add method but i dont know how apply it

```
                   if (pag.Name.ToString() == "Inicio.aspx")
                {
                        var fileCreationInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                        fileCreationInfo.Url = "";
                        fileCreationInfo.ContentStream = pag.OpenBinaryStream().Value;
                        fileCreationInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pag);
                        fileCreationInfo.Overwrite = true;
                        var uploadFile = Destlist.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInfo);
                    }
```

Comment: It's not clear which is the issue you are encountering... Are you getting an error, as described in your question? Or you need a code example about how to copy a file?

Comment: oh, sorry for this, first i getting the error, but i resolved trying with the update code, now i want to copy the file in another site, thanks you and sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can use this extension method:

```
public static Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File CopyFileTo(this Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File sourceFile, ClientContext destCtx, string fileDestinationRelativeUrl)
{

    var sourceContext = sourceFile.Context as ClientContext;

    if (!sourceFile.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))
    {
        sourceContext.Load(sourceFile, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl);
        sourceContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(sourceContext, sourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destCtx, fileDestinationRelativeUrl, fileInfo.Stream, true);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spfile = destCtx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileDestinationRelativeUrl);
    destCtx.Load(spfile);
    destCtx.ExecuteQuery();

    return spfile;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
File file = list.RootFolder.Files.Where(x => x.Name == "Inicio.aspx").First();

ListItem srcListItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
clientcontext.Load(srcListItem);
clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

var fileLeafRef = file.ListItemAllFields["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
var newRelUrl = ""; // do someting with fileLeafRef --> replace source relative url with dest relative url
var newFile = file.CopyFileTo(clientcontext2, newRelUrl);
```

Comment: but the code for enable the feature works, i retrieve the page, only i dont know how copy the page to another site

Comment: Ok, I'll delete my answer because the problem you are encountering is another than the one described in your question...

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks so much, but im really new in sharepoint add in, and i dont know hot to implement this method, its a provides hosted add id in mvc :/

Comment: Just add a new static class to your project and insert there the method. Then call it as I described.